# Regex for dates format

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, date

I am working under the Web Application based on ASP.NET MVC 5 and I have a great problem in my project with the field which gives the user the ability to choose format for showing Dates in the application.

The goal is to make RegularExpressionAttribute with the regex for validation date formats inputted by user.

Acceptable formats must be:
**m/d/y,
m-d-y,
m:d:y,
d/m/y,
d-m-y,
d:m:y,
y/m/d,
y-m-d,
y:m:d**

and the length of the date symbols may be as **'y'** so far **'yyyy'**. And they can be **upper case**.

So after hard-coding I've made the acceptable one:

```
    ((([mM]{1,4})([\/]{1})([dD]{1,4})([\/]{1})([yY]{1,4}))|(([mM]{1,4})([\-]{1})([dD]{1,4})([\-]{1})([yY]{1,4}))|(([mM]{1,4})([\:]{1})([dD]{1,4})([\:]{1})([yY]{1,4})))|((([dD]{1,4})([\/]{1})([mM]{1,4})([\/]{1})([yY]{1,4}))|(([dD]{1,4})([\-]{1})([mM]{1,4})([\-]{1})([yY]{1,4}))|(([dD]{1,4})([\:]{1})([mM]{1,4})([\:]{1})([yY]{1,4})))|((([yY]{1,4})([\/]{1})([mM]{1,4})([\/]{1})([dD]{1,4}))|(([yY]{1,4})([\-]{1})([mM]{1,4})([\-]{1})([dD]{1,4}))|(([yY]{1,4})([\:]{1})([mM]{1,4})([\:]{1})([dD]{1,4})))|((([yY]{1,4})([\/]{1})([dD]{1,4})([\/]{1})([mM]{1,4}))|(([yY]{1,4})([\-]{1})([dD]{1,4})([\-]{1})([mM]{1,4}))|(([yY]{1,4})([\:]{1})([dD]{1,4})([\:]{1})([mM]{1,4})))
```

This one works... But according to my scarce regex knowledge and experience I hope to get some help and better example for resolving this puzzle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generalize a bit.

```
m{1,4}([:/-])d{1,4}\1y{1,4}|d{1,4}([:/-])m{1,4}\2y{1,4}|y{1,4}([:/-])m{1,4}\3d{1,4}
```

Explanation:
instead of e.g. [mM] use m and set option for case insensitive match
([:/-]) all allowed delimiters as group
\1...\3 back reference to the delimiter group 1...3

Comment: Its really working... Great thanks, i'll read it more and try to reproduce it by myself.